# OneToOne Relationship with a query

Tags: hibernate, spring-data, one-to-one

I'm currently working on migrating a code that uses JDBC (not designed for JPA) to Hibernate , and I have two entities that I want to link with a one-to-one relationship. 
Below are similar entities that can help explain my issue:

```
Entity A
 complexKey : String

Entity B
 complexSubKey1: String
 complexSubKey2: String
 complexSubKey3: String
```

for this example I would like to link entity A and B, when

> complexKey = complexSubKey1 + ":" + complexSubKey2 + ":" +
>   complexSubKey3.

and i genuily have no idea how to achieve this.

Comment: Have you created the pojos and mapping??relationship with a query...what exactly are you trying to achieve??

Comment: I'm working on a legacy code that haven't been designed for JPA ( and relationship) , i do have pojos but i but they're too cumbersome to put in this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to achieve that by using the `JoinColumnOrFormula` annotation

```
public class B{

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumnsOrFormulas(
           { 
              @JoinColumnOrFormula(
                 formula=@JoinFormula(value="concat(complexSubKey1,':','complexSubKey2',':',complexSubKey3)"
                     , referencedColumnName="complexKey")) 
           })
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    private A a;
}
```

Comment: Great. Glad I could help